# finding the limits of a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, math, matplotlib

I have the following 2 list mapped to each-other :

```
Values =[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,9,7,6,5.50,5,6,7,8,10,12,15,14 ,13.50 12]
Dates =[Day1,Day2,Day3,Day4,Day5,Day6,Day8,Day9,Day10,Day11,..,Day20]
```

[image]As you can see in the screenshot

I want to write a program  that will loop over the liste Values and return me the values of

```
XA= [X,A]
AB= [A,B]
BC=[B,C]
CD= [C,D]
DE=[D,E]
```

the challenge is that i dont know if the list will have only for Values from X to D or it will continue till N

I have try with the below code but the result is not giving me what i want because I need to figure out a way to store the values before continue with the process:

```
for Prs in close:


    # getung the high


    if Prs > SwingHigh:
        SwingHigh = Prs
        Swinglow=Prs


    elif Prs < Swinglow:
        Swinglow = Prs
        PrevHigh=SwingHigh

    else:
        PrevLow=Swinglow



    impulSizee = SwingHigh - InicialPrice
    retrSize = SwingHigh - Swinglow



    # geting the index if the lows low

    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('theprice testing',Prs)
    print('the starting price is InicialPrice ',InicialPrice)
    print('the swing low is PrevLow ',PrevLow)
    print('the swing hige is PrevHigh',PrevHigh)
    print('the new high SwingHigh ',SwingHigh)
    print('the new low Swinglow------ ',Swinglow)
```

Comment: I can understand A and C are the peaks, but what are X, B, and D?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ local minima, rather than local maxima. Or "troughs", vs. peaks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Really? There is only one "15" in this list, and both B and C appear to be equal to 15, so I'm confused...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think that's just a typo, looking at the list and the chart that label should be 5, not 15

Comment: Okay thanks, that clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [89]: from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

In [90]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,9,7,6,5.50,5,6,7,8,10,12,15,14 ,13.50, 12])

In [91]: idx = np.sort(np.concatenate((argrelextrema(a, np.greater)[0], argrelextrema(a, np.less)[0])))

In [92]: np.split(a, idx)
Out[92]:
[array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 8., 9.]),
 array([10. ,  9. ,  7. ,  6. ,  5.5]),
 array([ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8., 10., 12.]),
 array([15. , 14. , 13.5, 12. ])]
```

or

```
In [93]: np.split(a, idx+1)
Out[93]:
[array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  8.,  9., 10.]),
 array([9. , 7. , 6. , 5.5, 5. ]),
 array([ 6.,  7.,  8., 10., 12., 15.]),
 array([14. , 13.5, 12. ])]
```

Points of interest:

```
In [97]: np.concatenate((a[[0]], a[idx], a[[-1]]))
Out[97]: array([ 1., 10.,  5., 15., 12.])
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [129]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':Values, 
                             'Date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=len(Values))})

In [130]: df
Out[130]:
         Date  Value
0  2018-01-01    1.0
1  2018-01-02    2.0
2  2018-01-03    3.0
3  2018-01-04    4.0
4  2018-01-05    5.0
..        ...    ...
18 2018-01-19   12.0
19 2018-01-20   15.0
20 2018-01-21   14.0
21 2018-01-22   13.5
22 2018-01-23   12.0

[23 rows x 2 columns]

In [131]: idx = np.sort(np.concatenate((argrelextrema(df['Value'].values, np.greater)[0], 
                                        argrelextrema(df['Value'].values, np.less)[0])))

In [132]: idx
Out[132]: array([ 8, 13, 19], dtype=int64)

In [133]: df.iloc[idx]
Out[133]:
         Date  Value
8  2018-01-09   10.0
13 2018-01-14    5.0
19 2018-01-20   15.0

In [134]: poi = np.concatenate(([0], idx, [len(df)-1]))

In [135]: df.iloc[poi]
Out[135]:
         Date  Value
0  2018-01-01    1.0
8  2018-01-09   10.0
13 2018-01-14    5.0
19 2018-01-20   15.0
22 2018-01-23   12.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can not move the positions of the list elements because they are mapped with a list of dates I will edit my questions to add this information

Comment: the np.sort  is sort the list ?  it means that If I want to know when the Value B was made I will not get the correct day right ? Knowing that the entries are not unique

Comment: @Djalillounis, can you extend your question with the desired (output) data sets?

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and let you know if it works

Comment: I tried it out in a real scenario but it is not working ,  Can I DM for more details ?

Comment: @Djalillounis, try to open a new question and put there a small __reproducible__ sample data set and your desired data set...

Comment: I created a new question with more details :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370871/python-and-pandas-to-get-the-highs-and-lows

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas `shift` + `cumsum` trick in conjunction with a `groupby`:

```
s = pd.Series(values)
v = s.gt(s.shift(-1))
[g.tolist() for _, g in s.groupby(v.ne(v.shift()).cumsum())]

[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 9.0],   # XA
 [10.0, 9.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.5],                 # AB
 [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0],           # BC
 [15.0, 14.0, 13.5],                         # CD
 [12.0]]                                     # DE
```